# Powershell json loop with invoke-command

Tags: json, ansible

I've been trying to make this work for the last few hours so appreciate some help.
Trying to pass a json file as parameter to invoke and iterate through the loop like so:

```
        }

        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $myHV -ArgumentList $VMName,$finalState,$fileconfig -ScriptBlock{
            $VMName     = $args[0]
            $finalState = $args[1]
            $filecopy = $args[2]


            $json = Get-Content -Raw -Path $filecopy | ConvertFrom-Json
            $json | Select-Object -Property Name,Destination | ForEach-Object {

            foreach ($file in $json)  {
                   Copy-VMFile -verbose -Name $VMName -SourcePath c:\Temp\$VMName\$file.Name -DestinationPath $file.Destination -FileSource Host -Force        
            }
```

Unfortunately keep getting an error with the copy-vmfile function:

```
VERBOSE: Copy-VMFile will copy the file into the virtual machine "TEST123"
Failed to copy file "c:\Temp\testfolder\@{Name=hosts; Destination=\etc\}.Name" to "/etc" in the virtual machine.
```

My json is basically this:

```
[        
        {
            "Name":"hosts",
            "Destination":"/etc/"
        },
        {
            "Name":"resolv.conf",
            "Destination":"/etc/"
        }
]
```

I'm not sure why its "malforming" the string - this `"c:\Temp\testfolder\@{Name=hosts; Destination=\etc\}.Name"` is obviously should be `C:\Temp\testfolder\hosts`...why is it doing this?

Help!
J

Answer (score 0):

I think the backslash here in the `SourcePath` as caused an issue and probably needs to be escaped:

```
Copy-VMFile -verbose -Name $VMName -SourcePath c:\Temp\$VMName\$file.Name
```

I've fixed my code as below:

```
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $myHV -ArgumentList $VMName,$finalState,$fileconfig -ScriptBlock{
            $VMName     = $args[0]
            $finalState = $args[1]
            $fileconfig = $args[2]

            $json_object = (Get-Content -Path $fileconfig) -join "`n"  | ConvertFrom-Json
            ForEach ($object in $json_object.PsObject.Properties.value) {
               $filename = $object.Name
               Copy-VMFile -verbose -Name $VMName -SourcePath C:\Temp\$VMName\$filename -DestinationPath $object.Destination -FileSource Host -Force        
            }
```

I would love for someone to help comment on how I could escape the backslash successfully because the above method works and I'd like to know if there's a better way of doing it.

J